# Extract elements from list in Python to create nested list

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a list such as this (this is pulled from some html texts using bs4):

```
test = ['Raji GlovesSixSixOneRegular price\n$29.99\nSale price$9.95\n\n                Save 67%\n              \nBUY 2 GET 1 FREE',
 'Comp Vortex GlovesSixSixOneRegular price\n$29.99\nSale price$9.95\n\n                Save 67%\n              \nBUY 2 GET 1 FREE',
 "Shasta 3/4 Cycling Tights - Women'sSpecializedRegular price\n$70.00\nSale price$14.95\n\n                Save 79%",]

len(test) # 3
```

I want to loop through each line in the list (list of 3), and extract the 0,2nd and 4th indexed item for each line. so that the output looks like this:

This nested list contains all the items that I want to see.

```
out = [['Raji GlovesSixSixOneRegular price',
 'Sale price$9.95',
 '                Save 67%'],['Comp Vortex GlovesSixSixOneRegular price',
     'Sale price$9.95',
     '                Save 67%'],["Shasta 3/4 Cycling Tights - Women'sSpecializedRegular price",
 'Sale price$14.95',
 '                Save 79%']]
```

I know that I can extract the items from the **first** line like this:

```
item1 = test[0]
item1 = item1.split(sep = '\n')
item1
indices = [0,2,4]
values =[]
for i in indices:
    print(item1[i])
    values.append(item1[i])
    
values 


['Raji GlovesSixSixOneRegular price',
 'Sale price$9.95',
 '                Save 67%']
```

I am new to python, and I struggling to pull out these items from each line, and append them back in a nested list (see out above).

Any idea's for how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple list comprehension

```
test = ['Raji GlovesSixSixOneRegular price\n$29.99\nSale price$9.95\n\n                Save 67%\n              \nBUY 2 GET 1 FREE',
 'Comp Vortex GlovesSixSixOneRegular price\n$29.99\nSale price$9.95\n\n                Save 67%\n              \nBUY 2 GET 1 FREE',
 "Shasta 3/4 Cycling Tights - Women'sSpecializedRegular price\n$70.00\nSale price$14.95\n\n                Save 79%",]

values = [i.split(sep = '\n')[0:5:2] for i in test]
```

Comment: Wow that was so efficient! Thank you!

Comment: Could you please explain how the [0:5:2] part works?

Comment: Sure. This is the slice notation for python, and it works with the following format
``a[start:stop:step]``. It is a small for loop for indexes of a list. So I start at 0, end at 5 and take a step of 2. Do note that stop is exclusive so I had to write 5, not 4. More details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation and here https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/slice.html

Answer (score 2):

What about something like:

```
out = []
indices = [0, 2, 4]

for elem in test:
    aux = []
    elem_split = elem.split('\n')
    for index in indices:
        item = elem_split[index]
        aux.append(item)
    out.append(aux)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very easy to undertand

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below

```
values = []
for item1 in test:
    item1 = item1.split(sep = '\n')
    indices = [0,2,4]
    value = []
    for i in indices:
        value.append(item1[i])
    values.append(value)
print(values)
```